# Find the colour of a pixel at a given location without importing non-standard libraries

Tags: python, colors, pixel, python-2.6

I am in a situation where importing non-standard python libraries is not suitable. Is it possible to grab the pixel colour at a given location on the screen (x,y) using only the standard python (2.6) libraries in Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows this is possible since it's possible to call a DLL using Python, see [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252417/589206). You then can call the same DLL as specified in [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4839623/589206). Voila! The rest is just implementation ... now if you had asked if this were possible in an OS independent manner I'd be inclined to say no, but you explicitly stated this is on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

No, The std libraries can't tell you anything about your screen

Comment: Actually it is possible using ctypes and Windows dlls.