# What type of DC is returned by calling GetDC(NULL)?

Tags: winapi, gdi

The Windows API function [`GetDC()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdc) accepts a single parameter:

> **hWnd**
>
> > A handle to the window whose DC is to be retrieved. If this value is NULL, GetDC retrieves the DC for the entire screen.

Further down the page, the following is noted:

> After painting with a common DC, the `ReleaseDC` function must be called to release the DC. Class and private DCs do not have to be released. `ReleaseDC` must be called from the same thread that called `GetDC`. The number of DCs is limited only by available memory.

Unfortunately, it is unclear whether calling `ReleaseDC()` is necessary for a screen DC since its type is not mentioned anywhere. In fact, [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/display-device-contexts) describes five types of DCs; but none of them mention "screen".

Do I need to call `ReleaseDC()` on a screen DC?

Comment: By process of elimination, a screen DC cannot be a Class, Private, Window, or Parent
DC, so it has to be a Common DC, which must be released.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A screen DC is not a class DC, and it's not a private DC, so yes - it needs to be released.

Comment: Note that it is safe to call `ReleaseDC()` on class and private DCs, though. It is a no-op for them.