# Bat file to read color from screen's x and y coordinates

Tags: windows, batch-file, colors, keyboard-shortcuts, screen

How can I make the batch file check the color value at my screen at the exact x and y resolution coordinates? And if the color is black - output a keystroke?

Comment: Try pyautogui locate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting pixel color in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839623/getting-pixel-color-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Try with [getPixelColor.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/getPixelColor.bat)  it returns the color in ARGB code:

```
call getPixelColor 10 100

Color [A=255, R=90, G=154, B=216]
```